# How to use images in Angular2 with Webpack

Tags: image, angular, webpack

Application was created in Angular2 RC5. In RC5 (without webpack) everything worked fine. Images appeared as expected.

After upgrading to the final release of Angular 2.0.0 along with Webpack, images in my public folder no longer work anywhere in the application. Upgrade was done by creating a new fresh install of Angular2 with Webpack using the Angular CLI.

```
http://localhost:4200/images/thumbs/2016/09/16/IMG_3879.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

The same exact path works fine in RC5. What has to be done to be able to see images in the /public/images folder (Where they worked in RC5), or where should images be placed?

In my template I am calling the images with:

```
<img class="img-responsive" [src]="asset.thumb_local_path" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching, It seems that the image folder MUST be placed within either the src folder or the assets folder. This wasn't the case in RC5. Once I moved all of my images/videos/etc to the /assets folder I was now able to see them in the browser.

Comment: The problem is, in real world, parts of images are used by `Base64` url. `url-loader` can convert the image to `base64` url. So, copy the whole images directory doesn't make sense. What about the image size is just `1kb`? Do you really want to send a request to server for this?